# Почему sticky-блок игнорирует координаты left и right?

Tags: css, position, sticky

Мне нужно растянуть блок поиска так, чтобы он был на всю ширину экрана.
Этот блок помещен в main-контейнер с заданной шириной, видимо, поэтому не работает sticky-блок, однако, он же должен вести себя как абсолютно позиционированный блок и игнорировать родителя (в main контейнере position:relative не включен).

Как мне растянуть sticky-блок на всю ширину экрана?

```
/*блок родитель*/
.main {
    width: 1280px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: auto;
}

/* search box*/
.search-box {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticky-элемент, будет позиционироваться относительно *ближайшего предка в контейнере прокрутки*. Т.е. нам и не нужно было бы устанавливать `position:relative` для родительского элемента `.main` — он и так подпадает под эти условия, если является прямым родителем для `.search-box` в прокручиваемом элементе (документе).

Возможно, в вашем примере проблема вполне решается стилем `.search-box {position:fixed}`, но это не точно, т.к. html-код не показан в вопросе.

Comment: Не поможет.....

Comment: @Qwertiy если тут проблема только в том, чтобы сделать .search-box шире, чем родительский контейнер .main, и достаточно, чтобы он просто всегда был прилипшим вверху, то замена  position:sticky на position:fixed прекрасно поможет.

Comment: Да, сообразил сразу после задания вопроса. Это решает проблему, спасибо за ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Sticky работает не только по вертикали, но и по горизонтали. Так что с помощью left и right его позиционировать нельзя - они будут влиять только на горизонтальную прокрутку. Если дефаултное размещение блока устраивает, можно заменить их на ширину. Если не устраивает, то делай через 2 вложенных блока.